# How to reset Notification Area settings?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I am running Xubuntu with Xfce and today I accidentally removed an icon from the Notification Area that provided quick access to Thunderbird and Pidgin chats. Is there a way to restore that icon or to restore the whole Notification Area to default settings?

I marked the icon in question on the screenshot:

[image]

Apparently, I lost the volume icon, too.

UPDATE:
Apparently, I used the wrong nomenclature in my question. The icons I lost were not part of the Notification Area. They are a separate applet item called Indicator Plugin.

I found the icon on this very site

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **reinstall** the Xubuntu icons from the repositories and that will get your icons back.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xubuntu-icon-theme
```

---

I found this out by querying each of the icon folders with `dpkg -S`; for example:

```
dpkg -S /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce
```

which returned the name of the package they came from:

```
xubuntu-icon-theme: /usr/share/icons/elementary-xfce
```

---

If you have any other problems regarding settings you can purge the `xfce4-indicator-plugin` and then reinstall it with

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xfce4-indicator-plugin
```

If you have **also** removed the indicator from the Xfce panel, add it back again by right clicking the panel and clicking panel > add new items (see screenshot). Importantly, you will probably have to logout and login for the changes to take effect after reinstalling the icons.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for help. I must have just removed the indicator from the main panel.